# How do I wrap text nested in an anchor tag, within a span?

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="print">
  <p><a href="/">Printable Format</a></p>
</div>
```

However, I want to wrap "Printable Format" within a :

```
<div class="print">
  <p><a href="/"><span>Printable Format</span></a></p>
</div>
```

I have looked at several examples, but they don't seem to accomplish what I'm looking for.

Thank you in advance!

- B

Comment: This is really confusing. Can you just show the markup? like...`<span><a> Printable Format </a></span>` so we can help?

Answer (score 3):

Use [.contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) with [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

```
// 
$('.print').find('a').contents().wrap('<span/>')
// same as $('.print a').contents().wrap('<span/>')
```

or [wrapInner()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) - which does the same thing

```
$('.print').find('a').wrapInner('<span/>')
// same as $('.print a').wrapInner('<span/>')
```

Pure JS example for @Alfo

```
// returns an array of elements
var dtag = document.getElementsByClassName('print');
// gets first anchor tag inside first class=print
var atag = dtag[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
// add span tag
atag.innerHTML = '<span>' + atag.innerHTML+ '</span>';
```

If you want to do multiple elements, you will have to loop through the arrays

http://jsfiddle.net/KkAkk/

Comment: Isn't that assuming jQuery is loaded? Is there a way to do this without importing a whole Javascript library?

Comment: @Alfo OP tagged post with jQuery

Comment: @KevinBoucher my mistake. But for others who don't want to load it - is there a simple solution?

Comment: That assumption would be correct. Apologies for not initially stating that.

Comment: @Alfo I added an example for a simple js solution.. Though it doesn't do the same exact thing the jQuery will do

Comment: Thanks @Alfo! I'll keep in the event I need to use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.print a').html(function(i, h){
     return '<span>' + h + '</span>';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to do this with jQuery:

```
var $span = $( "<span></span>" ), // Create element
    $link = $( '.print > p > a' );

$span.text( $link.text() );
$link.html( $span );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.print a').wrapInner('<span/>');​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Will produce:

```
<a href="/"><span>Printable Format</span></a>
```

Here is the jQuery reference: http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/

Here is my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tracyfu/bHVtg/

Comment: Thanks Traci! I'm really dumbfounded by this! I tried the function several times, prior to you suggesting it. But it still isn't working. What am I doing wrong? Here's the link: http://ctevents.1105cms01.com/events/ct-forum-conference/home.aspx. Check out the Printable Format link (see social icons) below the Request Info button. The function is in script.js, and I'm using jQuery 1.7.2. I know the fix is something that should be obvious, but...

Comment: @BrionK.Mills When I loaded your page, I saw a console error in my Chrome inspector that says, `"Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object>" has no method 'carousel'` on line 54 in script.js. I'm just guessing, but because this occurs before your `wrapInner` it's causing the rest of your JS to fail to finish executing. I will try to debug and get back to you.

Comment: @BrionK.Mills One other thing... Your call to `wrapInner` has a small typo; should be `wrap...` instead of `wrapp...`

Comment: @BrionK.Mills Ok, so I called `wrapInner` in the console after your page loads and it appears to be working. Fixing the typo and carousel thing ought to get it working for you. I hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

With Pure Javascript you can try this

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('print')[0]
                   .getElementsByTagName('a')[0] ;

var html = elem.innerHTML;

elem.innerHTML = '<span class="red">'+ html + '</span>' ;
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/ZncZd/)**
​

Answer (score 0):

Set the break-word property to the span.

Example HTML:

```
<span class="wrapped-link"><a href="#">my link</a>
```

Example CSS

```
.wrapped-link{
    word-break: break-word;
}
```